# Vuex this.$store is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying learning vue with vux and vuetify. I've installed it via vue cli.

Like in the documentation, I try to get access of the store, but got an undefined for this.$storage.

src/components/HelloWorld.vue

```
<script>

export default {
  methods: {
    onChangeTheme: () => {
      console.log(this.$store)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

src/main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

src/store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {

  },
  mutations: {

  },
  actions: {

  }
})
```

Comment: When you try to use arrow function as vue methods you are losing the context of `this` that do reference to vue instance. Careful there isn't recommend do it, just you should use normal function declaration

Comment: Thank you very much, this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as `created: () => console.log(this.a)` or `vm.$watch('a', newValue => this.myMethod())`. Since an arrow function doesn’t have a this, this will be treated as any other variable and lexically looked up through parent scopes until found, often resulting in errors such as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function.

This is explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods).

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to use arrow function and pass the store as a parameter? Something like:  ``` onChangeTheme: ({store}) => store.someData```